# Changing your 20 indexed columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a large SharePoint 0365 list of over 15,000 items. I have already used all 20 indexed columns. I now need to filter by a different column. Is it safe for me to remove an indexed column and changed to a different field? Do you have to reindex the list, if I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll find that creating or removing column indexes are among the operations that are restricted upon surpassing SharePoint's list view threshold, as documented [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784).

In an on-premises SharePoint farm (or an otherwise traditional SharePoint farm using cloud-hosted infrastructure), you'd have access to central administration where you could temporarily increase the threshold, set a time window during which the threshold won't apply, or even use Powershell to temporarily set the `EnableThrottling` property of the list to false, allowing you to make your indexed column changes. But with Office 365 you won't have any of those options.

Depending on the circumstances, you can still circumvent the list view threshold when filtering by first filtering the list by one or more of your indexed columns such that less than 5000 items are returned; you should then be able to filter that subset of results using your unindexed column.

Another alternative would be to use SharePoint's search services to access results in your list that match the given metadata. Since the search crawl index is generated ahead of time (rather than a live query), it is not beholden to the list view threshold. Only problem there is that the results might be stale depending on the frequency of search crawls.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have 20 indexed columns, it is possible that you might be able to query the list using an already-indexed column to return a response that obeys the list-view threshold ('Date Created' range, or 'Created By' might be useful columns)

Once you return your initial response, you can then filter on the unindexed column of interest.